# Have a script (JS) run when I click the month button

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to figure out how to have a script run when I select "month" in a full calendar derivative.

How would I go about this? Click it and EVERYTHING else happens, but a script of my choosing also runs.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I'm trying to even figure out WHERE I would do so! The only JS file in the calendar that I can find, is incomprehensible. It's a solid block of code, with no comments, line breaks, or even discernable functions.

Comment: That sounds like the description of a minified JS which means you are really lost there.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The FullCalendar documentation is arguably the best open source documentation I've ever seen. Complete, up to date, well written.

Answer (score 0):

regardless of whether you are using the select or dayclick, you should be able to have a function run within that callback and then use $.ajax function to run your php script (assuming you are using php since you did not specify). Here is a short example...

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
select: function(s, e, a) {
  myfunction();
}
});
```

And then outside of the calendar var...

```
function myfunction(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'myscript.php',
    data: {myvariable: myvariable},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

I cant see why this wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ... you can have other things here ...

    $('.fc-button-month > .fc-button-inner').live('click', function() {
        alert('I am here ..');
    });
});
```